# How unslant (emph) some text in a newtx theorem?

Tags: thmtools, newtx

Using `newtx` for fonts and declaring theorems using `thmtools`, I want the body of theorem-like environments to be slanted. With `newtx`, specifying `\thfamily` for the `bodyfont` does that.

However, I still want to cause some text within a theorem body to be upright, using `\emph` as usual.

But this is not working. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[thmslshape]{newtx}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\swapnumbers

% see newtexdoc.pdf, page 12, end of Section 5:
\newcommand\thmbodyfont{\thfamily} 

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em plus 2pt minus 2pt,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\thmbodyfont,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=section]{theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.
\end{theorem}


Compare:

{\slshape If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.}

\emph{If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.}

\end{document}
```

[image: emph issue with slant theorembody font with newtx]

Comment: What about using the  `trueslanted` option for `newtx` package and then `bodyfont=\slshape` in the theorem style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically can't. The slanted theorem font has

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{ntxth-tlf}{\ntx@spacing}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ntxth-tlf}{m}{it}{<-> \ntx@scaled ntxth-\ntx@thrmshape-tlf-ot1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ntxth-tlf}{m}{n}{<->ssub * ntxth-tlf/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ntxth-tlf}{m}{sc}{<->ssub * ntxth-tlf/m/it}{}
```

and other similar substitution follow. This means that `\emph` will switch to the upright font `\OT1/ntxth-tlf/m/n/10` font, which turns out to be the same as the slanted one.

Workaround: surgery to `\emph`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[thmslshape,trueslanted]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\swapnumbers

\NewCommandCopy{\latexemph}{\emph}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\emph}{m}{%
  \ifthfamily
    \expandafter\textnormal
  \else
    \expandafter\latexemph
  \fi{#1}%
}
\newif\ifthfamily
\AddToHook{cmd/thfamily/before}{\thfamilytrue}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em plus 2pt minus 2pt,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\thfamily,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=section]{theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range (with upright parentheses).
\end{theorem}

Compare:

{\slshape If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.}

\emph{If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.}

\end{document}
```

We redefine `\emph` to be the standard command except when `\thfamily` is in force, when it does `\textnormal`. The check could be more detailed, but you won't have emphasis inside emphasis in those cases, I hope.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[trueslanted]{newtx} % <-- added option

\usepackage{thmtools}
\swapnumbers

% see newtexdoc.pdf, page 12, end of Section 5:
% \newcommand\thmbodyfont{\thfamily} % <-- no needed anymore

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em plus 2pt minus 2pt,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\slshape, %                 <-- using default slshape command
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=section]{theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.
\end{theorem}


Compare:

{\slshape If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.}

\emph{If the domain of a continuous \emph{open} surjection is locally compact,
then so is its range.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, that works. But now I guess there's no good alternative to having manually to make upright any parentheses and brackets that appear within a theorem body.

Comment: The purpose of `\thfamily` is to have a slanted (or italic) font with upright parentheses and punctuation and you're defeating it.

Comment: @egreg, yes, I didn't know about that. Now I saw your answer and it should be the accepted one. I'll delete mine.

Comment: @murray, please, accept the egreg's answer instead of mine.

Comment: @Sigur: keep yours, please, which *does* work even though it doesn't make parentheses and brackets upright (egreg's answer does take care of that, too).